# SVG Координаты объекта через jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg, javascript, raphael

Здравствуйте! 
Имеется интерактивная карта здания. Нужно создать визуальный редактор карты, по такому принципу: Указываем крайние точки объекта, узнаем координаты.
Подложка - png изображение.
Работаю с библиотекой `Raphael` для визуализации.

**Вопрос:** как узнать координаты в таком виде, как с SVG изображения.

```
path = "M313,847L353,847L353,787L353,779L308,779L308,847"
```

Comment: а при чем тут jquery ?

Comment: редактор карты пишу с использованием jQuery. Указал для того, чтобы при возможности упомянули нужную функцию.

Comment: Не совсем понял что нужно узнать, в любом случае стоит начать с документации [SVGPathElement](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/object/101), вероятно понадобится свойство normalizedPathSegList.

Comment: Допустим пользователь отмечает 4 точки на рисунке, создавая "квадрат". Нужно узнать координаты области "квадрат" в указанном формате.

Comment: @DreammakeR, ну а в чем проблема? Не знаю как с Raphael, но на чистом js это делается примерно так: запоминаете координаты кликов, форматируете строку d, создаете dom элемент для path (не забудьте указать namespace svg), добавляете в него аттрибут d, ну и еще какие пожелаете, добавляете получившийся элемент в нужное место в svg.

Comment: ну вообще-то для создания path в svg не обязательно нужен такой формат, можно указывать и абсолютные координаты. опять же на чистом js можно создавать сегменты пути опять же без этого формата, а заданными как относительно, так и абсолютно. постановка задачи в вопросе получения какой-то строки по итогам каких-то действий пользователя выглядит не совсем тем, что реально нужно получить...

Answer (score 2):

Для решения проблемы использовал готовый [редактор карт](http://summerstyle.github.io/summer/) Summer (статья о нем на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/152731/)).

В базе координаты были нужны в виде:

```
path = "M313,847L353,847L353,787L353,779L308,779L308,847"
```

Данный редактор работал с координатами в виде:

```
 <area shape="poly" coords="313,847,353,847,353,787,353,779,308,779,308,847" />
```

Как вы можете увидеть разница в том, что во втором случае просто нет символов.

Написал маленький парсер для базы (может кому пригодится).

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $col_value = $line['path'];
  $col_value = str_replace(array('M', ' '), '', $col_value);
  $col_value = str_replace(array('Z', ' '), '', $col_value);
  $col_value = str_replace(array('C'),',',$col_value);
  $col_value = str_replace(array('L'),',',$col_value);
}
```

Получил координаты в нужном в виде и загружал в редактор.

**Всем спасибо за внимание!**

Comment: @DreammakeR, может все-таки лучше так:

    $path = "M313,847L353,847L353,787L353,779L308,779L308,847";
    $res = preg_split('/[MZCL,]+/',$path);

Результат:

    Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 313
        [2] => 847
        [3] => 353
        [4] => 847
        [5] => 353
        [6] => 787
        [7] => 353
        [8] => 779
        [9] => 308
        [10] => 779
        [11] => 308
        [12] => 847
    )

Остается только убрать пустые значения массива. Напр., array_filter()